# Create an MD5 encryption function using pure XSL

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I need to write an MD5 encryption function, using pure XSLT or anything else compatible Saxon's XSL 3.0 merging engine (i.e. not, for example, JavaScript).

Anyone knows a compatible code I can use for this purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any existing code for this. The MD5 algorithm uses bitwise operators (and, or, not, xor) on 32-bit quantities. These operators are not available as standard in XSLT/XPath, but they are implemented in the EXPath Binary module (http://expath.org/spec/binary#bitwise) which is available in Saxon (-PE or -EE), and with the help of these functions I don't see any intrinsic difficulty in implementing the algorithm.

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to implement MD5 using the 'bin' namespace, currently only on one line of code: <xsl:variable name="firstCharPos" select="bin:shift(bin:hex('000001'), 17)"/>
I keep getting the following error: "Namespace prefix bin is not declared". I am using Saxon -PE. What am I doing something wrong? Should I include the binary library somehow?

Comment: My stylesheet element looks like that: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    extension-element-prefixes="saxon"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs saxon mf"
    version="3.0">, should 'bin' be included here? Couldn't find any documentation for it @michaelkay